# Firestore: save document reference or document id?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I try to link a document to another document in my database. As far as I understand, I can save the ID or a reference to it.

What's the difference between those methods and which one suits me better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple string document ID has no context while a `Reference` contains the entire path to a document. For the ease of use in a [custom objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#custom_objects) it will be useful to have the entire `Reference` object stored.

When [writing queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) you can also filter on a `Reference` object in the database by comparing it to another.

However, it's a personal preference. Anything that a string can do, `Reference` can also provide. Having a `Reference` type can saves you for trouble of building a new `Reference` object in your code and you can also use it in security rules for the same purpose when it comes time to use `get()` to fetch another document referenced by a field.